# Helper function in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra to monitor a server. I need to read the list of folders in a master folder, and the content of meta.xml inside each folder. This is the desired output:

```
<folders>
    <folder 1>
        <meta.xml content>
    <folder 2>
        <meta.xml content>
<\folders>
```

This is my current code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'haml'

get '/processed' do
    status 200
    meeting_dir="/home/default"
    Dir.entries(meeting_dir)
end
```

I'm confused about Sinatra printing the values of all the variable inside the get block. If I want to write a subfunction getxml to generate the xml, where should I put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Helpers):

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'haml'

helpers do
  def get_xml( *args )
    # your code here…
  end
end

get '/processed' do
  # getxml is available here
  status 200
  meeting_dir="/home/default"
  Dir.entries(meeting_dir)
end
```

Now, I'm assuming that you want the output to XML, so that route won't work, you'll get the evaluation of the last expression, which is currently `Dir.entries(meeting_dir)`.

Set up a [view](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Views%20/%20Templates), and using [Haml's `list_of` helper](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#list_of-instance_method) we'll get it ready to output the list of values:

```
#views/contents.haml

<folders>
  = list_of(@metas) do |meta|
   = "<#{meta.name}>"
     = meta.content
   = "</#{meta.name}>"
<\folders>
```

Now you need a `@metas` object:

```
helpers do

  def get_xml( meeting_dir )
    dirs = Dir.entries(meeting_dir).reject{|e| e.start_with? "." }
    meta = Struct.new(:name, :content)
    dirs.each_with_object([]) do |d,metas|
      meta.name = d # it's up to you whether you 
                    # want the absolute or relative path here
      meta.content = File.read File.expand_path(File.join d, "meta.xml")
      metas << meta
    end
    # the return value of each_with_object
    # is the object, so no need for a return expression
  end
end

get '/processed', :provides => :xml do
  # status 200 <- this is not needed
  meeting_dir="/home/default"
  @metas = get_xml(meeting_dir)
  haml :contents, :layout => false
end
```

Also look at http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Conditions and http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Named%20Templates. That should give you something to be going on with.